# Simple mapping configuration List<Object> field

Tags: java, orika

I'm trying to map two classes with almost the same fields: `MetaInfoDTO` and `MetaInfo`.

I've tried to configure the mapper with a default mapping. The problem is on the `List<Object> values` field. It has the same name on the other class. So, I guess it have to be mapped correctly. See the test at the end.

```
public class MetaInfoDTO
{

    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String description;
    private List<Object> values;

    //Constructors, getters and setters...
    public List<Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}

public class MetaInfo
{

    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String description;
    private List<Object> values;

    //Constructors, getters and setters...
    public List<Object> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<Object> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

And this orika configuration:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(MetaInfoDTO.class, MetaInfo.class)
        .byDefault()
        .register();
```

I've created a test in order to show my problem:

```
@Test
public void metaInfoDTOTOMetaInfoWITHVALUES()
{
    MetaInfoDTO dto = new StringMetaInfoDTO("key1", "desc1");
    MetaInfo metainfo = this.mappingResources.getMapper().map(dto, MetaInfo.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        dto.getValues().add("s" + i);

    assertThat(dto.getValues(), not(empty()));
    assertThat(metainfo.getValues(), not(empty()));   //<<<< IT'S EMPTY!!
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class StringMetaInfoDTO extends MetaInfoDTO
{

    public StringMetaInfoDTO(String key, String description) {
        this(key, description, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    public StringMetaInfoDTO(String key, String description, List<String> values) {
        super(MetaInfoTypeDTO.stringType, key, description, values.stream().map(e -> (Object)e).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

}
```

So, after mapping, `metainfo.getValues()` is empty!
Is there something wrong?

Comment: Please add the code of `StringMetaInfoDTO`. Do you have a ClassMap for StringMetaInfoDTO type? I can see you are adding values to `dto` after you executed `map(dto, MetaInfo.class)` - how do you expect the `metainfo` values to be filled in?

Comment: I've added `StringMetaInfoDTO` class. No, I've not a map configuration on my `Mapper` for it. Mmmm, I'm stupid!